# Get the color from my JButtons

Tags: java, swing, events, colors, get

I need to make a frame with some buttons in a bar at the bottom. All my buttons show an image with a color, e.g. black, gray, white and so on. I have a panel that I can draw on  with the color I picked. The problem is that I don't know how to make a method to catch that color when I press the button.

```
private JToolBar barreOutils;

// 
private JToggleButton[] btnTab = new JToggleButton[9];

// 
private String[] btnName = { "Couleur noire", "Couleur grise",
        "Couleur blanche", "Couleur rouge", "Couleur orange",
        "Couleur jaune", "Couleur verte", "Couleur cyan", "Couleur bleue" };

// 
private String[] btnColor = { "dark.gif", "gray.gif", "white.gif",
        "rouge.gif", "orange.gif", "yellow.gif", "vert.gif", "cyan.gif",
        "blue.gif" };

String[] colorTab = { "Color.DARK", "Color.GRAY", "Color.WHITE",
        "Color.RED", "Color.ORANGE", "Color.YELLOW", "Color.GREEN",
        "Color.CYAN", "Color.BLUE" };

// buttonGroup
private ButtonGroup groupeCouleurs;
// Notre panneau principal
private JPanel panneau;

public Fenetre() {

    // Organization
    setTitle("Application");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(600, 600);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    // Organization
    panneau = new JPanel();
    panneau.setBackground(Color.white);
    panneau.addMouseListener(new Dessiner());
    panneau.addMouseMotionListener(new Dessiner());
    getContentPane().add(panneau);

    // 
    barreOutils = createToolbar();
    getContentPane().add(barreOutils, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

}

private JToolBar createToolbar() {

    JLabel couleur = new JLabel("Couleurs : ");
    barreOutils = new JToolBar();


    groupeCouleurs = new ButtonGroup();
    barreOutils.add(couleur);


    createButton(btnTab, btnName, btnColor);

    return barreOutils;
}

private void createButton(JToggleButton[] btnTab, String[] btnName,
        String[] btnColor) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    // add the buttons on the bar at the bottom
    for (int indBtn = 0; indBtn < btnTab.length; indBtn++) {
        btnTab[indBtn] = new JToggleButton(new ImageIcon(
                Fenetre.class.getResource(btnColor[indBtn])));
        btnTab[indBtn].setToolTipText(btnName[indBtn]);
        groupeCouleurs.add(btnTab[indBtn]);
        barreOutils.add(btnTab[indBtn]);
    }
}

private class Dessiner extends MouseAdapter {

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Graphics g = ((JComponent) e.getSource()).getGraphics();
        g.setColor(**???????????????????????**);
        g.drawOval(e.getX(), e.getY(), 1, 1);

    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Suggestions:

- Set the button's actionCommand via `btnTab[indBtn].setActionCommand(btnName[indBtn]);`
- The ButtonGroup can tell you which Button was selected by getting the selection which will be a ButtonModel object if a selection was made or null if no selection is present.
- Get the selected buttons' actionCommand String from the ButtonModel above by calling its `getActionCommand()` method.
- Consider using a `HashMap<String, Color>` to link the actionCommand String with its associated color.

Also

- Don't get a component's Grahpics via getGraphics. Instead do your drawing in a BufferedImage and then draw the BufferedImage in a JComponent (or a class that extends JComponent such as JPanel)'s paintComponent method.
- You would get the Graphics object from the BufferedImage by calling getGraphics() on it, but just be sure to delete the Graphics object when you're through with it.
- In your MouseListener change the object's state by changing class fields, then call repaint.

Answer (score 2):

You could extend JToggleButton and have that class contain whatever information you want.

```
class ColorButton extends JToggleButton {

  private Color color;

  public ColorButton(Color c) {
    super();
    this.color = c;
  }

  public Color getColor() {
    return color;
  }
}
```

Comment: This could work too -- 1+. Or another solution is to use a HashMap<String, Color> matching the JToggleButton's actionCommand String with a Color.

Answer (score 0):

i noticed  you have the color names in the buttons image name, why not grab it from there.

Comment: Because I tried to do an action events to catch the color from my clicked button but it failed. I don't know :(